# how to add external json values in ionic2

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a json data in one js file.in IONIC2 i need to get that value from that file and assign to an another variable in constructor..? how to achieve this

```
export class RangenavigatorDefaultPage {
  rangeData: any;
  constructor(private nav: NavController,) {
     rangeData = //need to add that json variable from external js
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

export the json data from the file. import the json into this file.

FILE 1:

```
export settings = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
```

FILE 2:

```
import { settings } from './file1';
```